# Apply changes to all items of recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerview in my app in which list of videos are playing. Each item of recyclerview have a "Mute" button. I want when i click on Mute button of any item all the other Mute buttons on other items also change to "UnMute". Something like "apply one change to all item on one click". Please help

Comment: You're probably filling your items from an array or a list... Why not just loop over all of them and set their mute flag to `false` and then calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` for the view to update.

Comment: Ok I will try this solution.